# How do I sum similarly named variables in SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to remove every observation where the variable starting with R1 has a missing value. In order to do this, I first try to sum every variable with that prefix:

```
data test
input R1_1 R1_2 R1_3;
datalines;
. . .
;
run;
data test2;
set test;
diagnosis=sum (of R1:);
run;
```

This syntax should work according to [this article](https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2012/TA/PharmaSUG-2012-TA05.pdf). However something seems to be wrong. In the above example, I get an error complaining about the function call not having enough arguments. In other cases, the code seems to run smoothly but my diagnosis variable isn't created.

Can I fix this and in that case how?

Comment: You have a missing semi-colon on the first line.

Comment: Fix the first error.  Because of the missing semicolon on the first line you did not create any variables. Instead you created five empty datasets named test input R1_1 R1_2 and R1_3.

Comment: Why would you remove observations with missing values by summing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because you did not have a semicolon ending the DATA statement so the TEST dataset you created does not have any variables.  Instead you also created datasets named INPUT R1_1 R1_2 and R1_3 that also did not have any variables.

To your actual question you can use NMISS() to count the number of missing numeric values.

```
nmiss = nmiss(of R1_:) ;
```

So you can eliminate observations with ANY missing values by using something like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  where nmiss(of R1_1-R1_3);
run;
```

If the goal is to remove observations where ALL of the values are missing you need to know how many variables you are testing.  If you don't know that number in advance then you could use an ARRAY to count them.  But then you would need to use a subsetting IF instead of WHERE.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array x r1_: ;
  if nmiss(of r1_:) < dim(x);
run;
```

If you have a mix of numeric and character variables you can use CMISS() instead.

Comment: Regarding `where nmiss(of R1_1-R1_3);`   The where processor does not handle `of <namelist>` syntax.  Use `if nmiss(of R1_1-R1_3)=0;` or an explicit list `where nmiss(R1_1,R1_2,R1_3)=0`